# Swisscom CloudFoundry with SSH keys

Tags: wordpress, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I try to install Wordpress on the Swisscom CloudFoundry application cloud. To install it I need SSH with private and public key pairs (not cf ssh).

I follow the steps here:
https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/cf-ex-wordpress

Is this possible? What are the correct values for:

```
SSH_HOST: user@my-ssh-server.name
SSH_PATH: /home/sshfs/remote
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible?

It depends on your CF provider.  This method of running Wordpress requires that you use a FUSE filesystem (SSHFS) to mount the remote files system over the `wp-content` directory of your Wordpress install.  In recent versions of CF (I can't remember exactly where this changed) you are no longer allowed to use FUSE based file systems.

Before you spend a lot of time on this, you might want to validate that your provider still allows FUSE.  You can validate with a simple test.

1. Push any test app to your provider.
2. `cf ssh` into the application container.
3. Check that the `sshfs` binary is available.
4. Try using `sshfs` to mount a remote filesystem ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs) | [examples](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-mount-remote-directory-filesystems-with-sshfs-on-linux/)).

If you can successfully mount a remote filesystem via SSH using the steps above then you should still be able to use the method described in that example application.

If you cannot, the next best option is to use a plugin that allows storing your media on a remote system.  Most of these are for S3.  Search google or the WP plugin repo, they're easy enough to find.

There is a better solution on the horizon called Volume Services.  You can read more about this [here](http://cf-dev.70369.x6.nabble.com/cf-dev-Announcing-Volume-Services-for-Cloud-Foundry-td5785.html).  I have not seen any public CF providers offering volume services though.

> What are the correct values for:
>
> SSH_HOST: user@my-ssh-server.name

This should be the user name and host name of your SSH server.  This is a server that exists outside of CF.  Examples: my-user@192.0.2.10  or some-user@host.example.com.  You should be able to `ssh <this-value>` and connect without entering a password.  This is so that the volume can automatically be mounted without user interaction when your app starts.

> SSH_PATH: /home/sshfs/remote

This is the full path on the remote server where you'd like to store the Wordpress files.  In other words, this directory will be mounted as the `wp-content` directory of your app.

Comment: I setup an external server and was able to connect to it from my cf app: 
`ssh -p 22 user@external-server.ch -i ./.ssh/sshfs.`

But sshfs gives me a permission error:
`$ sshfs user@external-server.ch:wordpress ./test
fusermount: failed to open /etc/fuse.conf: Permission denied`

Comment: As mentioned above, `sshfs` requires FUSE.  FUSE was disabled a while back in CF by default.  It's up to the provider, if it is enabled or disabled.  I would imagine most public providers are not going to allow it since it presents security risks.  You're getting an error, so I suspect your provider does not allow it.

Comment: @Gruenemuetze`diego_privileged_containers: false` in Swisscom App Cloud. It means you can't use FUSE. Please contact Swisscom Support why we should enable that / your use case. We will check that with security. Also in PWS FUSE is disabled, see https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/issues/1106